# cabal install d3js error

Tags: haskell, cabal

I got an error when installing d3js. I'm using ghc-7.8.3, cabal-1.22, debian Wheezy.

```
# cabal install d3js
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: d3js-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of d3js-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.7.0.1/installed-1a5... (conflict: d3js => > base>=4.6 && <4.7)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0,
4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0,
4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed instance) Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Comment: What is the output of `cabal info base`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cabal's error message could ideally be a lot better in this case. Anyway, what it means is:

- The package d3js has a dependency on base-4.6.*
- You're using GHC 7.8, which ships with base-4.7.0.1
- base is a special package (wired in), so I can't install a new version
- So, I can't install the package for you with this GHC version

Your options are:

- Try again with the `--allow-newer` flag
- Install GHC 7.6 and try with that